# Como saber as dimensões de uma imagem que está em array de bytes ou base64?

Tags: c#, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var binario = _documentoWord.Content.EnhMetaFileBits;
string img64Bytes = "";

var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binario, 0, binario.Length);
byte[] imageBytesBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

MemoryStream ms64 = new MemoryStream(imageBytesBase64);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms64);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    img64Bytes = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
}

var url = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + img64Bytes + "' />";
```

Nesse código eu transformo um arquivo word em uma imagem (array de bytes, e em seguida base64). Porém preciso saber quais as dimensões da imagem criada. (E como plus, se possível, redimensioná-la).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri. Inseri essas duas linhas dentro do using, pode ser depois também:

```
var largura = img.Width.ToString();
var altura = img.Height.ToString();
```

Ficou assim:

```
var binario = _documentoWord.Content.EnhMetaFileBits;
string img64Bytes = "";

var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binario, 0, binario.Length);
byte[] imageBytesBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

MemoryStream ms64 = new MemoryStream(imageBytesBase64);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms64);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    var largura = img.Width.ToString();
    var altura = img.Height.ToString();

    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    img64Bytes = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
}

var url = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + img64Bytes + "' />";
```